# Were the strong men exploits real or special effects in Mighty Joe Young?

Tags: mighty-joe-young

There is a scene in *Mighty Joe Young* where the giant ape is part of a nightclub cabaret act, this involves it competing against ten 'strong men' who are in the old circus act tradition of dressing like Fred Flintstone.

The nightclub compere initially has these men standing in a line, as he works down the line introducing them they step forward one by one.

Each man then does a demonstration of his strength, one straightens a horseshoe, one bends a thick crowbar, one tears a thick phonebook in half etc etc.

Were those feats really performed by these characters or was it special effects?

Comment: Timestamp?: https://archive.org/details/MightyJoeYoungNtsc

Comment: This might be a better fit for Movies & TV

Comment: @BinaryWorrier This question is fine here as it is; the work is fantasy so on topic.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot while I agree that is seems to be on topic _here_, it might be a better fit for [movies.se] nonetheless.

Comment: @SQB It might be but it's fine here so no point moving it. This is also gathering close votes, presumably because people think it should be on MTV, so I want to put that to bed that, that is not necessarily the case.

Comment: Those all sounds like legit feats of strength, and the actors in question were all professional wrestlers: "The strongmen who appeared in the "tug-of-war" scene with Joe were all professional wrestlers. They were: Sammy Stein, Slammin' Sammy Meneker, Max the Iron Man, Bomber Henry Kulky, Killer Karl Davis, Rasputin the Mad Russian, Wee Willie Davis, Man Mountain Dean, The Swedish Angel, and Primo Carnera. Carnera had briefly been the World Heavywight Boxing Champion. Dean, Kulky, and Davis also had careers in movies and TV. "

Comment: @FuzzyBoots After researching around quite a lot, especially for Ian "Mac" Batchelor, they don't all appear to have been pro wrestlers but all were known as strongmen. i.e. Primo Carnera was a professional boxer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:** All are strongmen in their own right and so likely did these feats of strength themselves specially considering that there were common party tricks at the time. Especially for professional wrestlers.

---

The actors who played the strongmen are according to IMDb's [cast page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0041650/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) and [trivia page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0041650/trivia?ref_=tt_ql_trv_1) and [Oldtime Strongman](https://www.oldtimestrongman.com/blog/2016/06/20/mighty-joe-young-vs-10-strongmen/):

- Ian "Mac" Batchelor - There's not much about Ian out there but according to [this source](http://wrestlingclassics.com/cgi-bin/.ubbcgi/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=get_topic;f=9;t=073552;p=0) he was apparently a bartender that worked from across the street from the studio (sourced from the DVD) and "was well-known in his day for arm-wrestling and performing feats of grip strength". He was also known as "Max the Iron Man".
- Primo Carnera - The ["Ambling Alp"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primo_Carnera), a professional boxer and actually the World Heavyweight Champion for a time.
- Karl Davis - Karl "Killer" Davis was a ex professional wrestler and apparently played football for the University of Ohio.
- William Davis - William "Wee Willie" Davis was a professional wrestler.
- Henry Kulky - He was a amateur boxer turned professional wrestler under the name "Bomber Kulkavich". He is also said to have ["won the South American judo crown."](http://slam.canoe.com/Slam/Wrestling/Movies/2007/10/27/4610208.html).
- Sammy Menacker - Slammin' Sam Menacker was a professional wrestler. He was apparently also a class A baseball player beforehand.
- Frank Simmons Leavitt - Better known as Man Mountain Dean he was again a professional wrestler. Beforehand he was actually into athletics and was part of a professional football team.
- Ivan Rasputin - Another professional wrestler.
- Sammy Stein - A professional wrestler and football player. He had a match for the World's Heavyweight Wrestling Championship but lost.
- Phil Olafsson - Better known as "The Swedish Angel" (not to be confused as Tor Johnson who went by the same name). He was also a professional wrestler.

All of these men are strongmen in their own right and the feats of strength are plausible as such I'd say they did them themselves. However, I have no explicit evidence either way.

According to user montgomerydou55 on film|boards this is what each person did:

> 1. **Sammy Stein**--broke a chain.
> 2. **Karl "Killer" Davis**--bent a crowbar.
> 3. **Ivan Rasputin** ("The Mad Russian")--broke manacles on his wrists.
> 4. **Henry Kulky** ("Bomber")--Lifted big barbells.
> 5. **Sammy Menacker** ("Slammin' Sammy")--tore a telephone book in two.
> 6. **Ian Batchelor** ("Max the Iron Man')--bent a railroad spike.
> 7. **William "Wee Willie" Davis** ("He's got fur!")--bent a long steel rod behind his head.
> 8. **Man Mountain Dean**--bent a horseshoe.
> 9. **Phil Olafsson** ("The Swedish Angel")--broke a 4x4 over his bald head.
> 10. **Primo Carnera**--flexed his biceps and snapped metal bands off them.
>
> <sub>[film|boards, Mighty Joe Young : The Wrestlers](https://www.filmboards.com/board/p/1888918/)</sub>

Comment: These are pretty common 'party tricks' for pro-wrestlers in this era

Comment: Moreover, you can find Youtube videos of people doing all of them (or close variations) now.